# Passing jQuery VAR STRING to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, submit

I have an a few var in jQuery that I want to send to PHP when I submit my form, which would be the best way of doing this? Is there a better way than just using hidden inputs and forcing their values with jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes... other than hidden inputs you can use jquery [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or [post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) or [get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)..

here is an example(using $.post) to get you going..

```
  var test=firstData;
  var test2=secondData;
  $.post('url(test.php)',{data1:test,data2:test2},function(result){
      alert("posted");
  })
```

from above..

url : is  where you want to send the data (php); 
second paremeter is data you want to send to server side script(php)
and third is the response from server.

test.php

```
$data1=$_POST['data1']; //gives you firstData
$data2=$_POST['data2'];  //gives you secondData
```

Comment: glad it helped.. go through the docs to read more about post...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax to submit the form. Serialize the form as below.

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    var data = $('form').serialize();
});
```

value of data will be in the form of query string

Append the var to the data and submit in ajax. You will get both the form data and the var value in php

Comment: Thank you so much, makes a lot more sense!